# How to resolve "invalid number of 'breaks'"

Tags: r

Code:

```
 f_custdata <- gsub(".", "", f_custdata)  
 f_custdata <- as.numeric(f_custdata) 
 hist(f_custdata)
```

Error: Error in hist.default(f_custdata) : invalid number of 'breaks'

[image: Sample in R of data]

I've also tried:

```
  df_custdata <- gsub(".", "", df_custdata)  
  df_custdata <- as.numeric(df_custdata$income) 
  hist(df_custdata)
```

It gives me 2 errors:

Error in df_custdata$income : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

AND

Error in hist.default(df_custdata) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what's inside your `f_custdata`?

Comment: Sure, I posted it above as it's shown in r.

Comment: That's the original?  What does it look like after the first two lines of code?

Comment: Nothing, it goes to the next > after running it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your data isn't actually a 2-dimensional frame, just a 1-dimensional series of strings.  (Hence the error when you try to select out an income column.)  So casting to numeric doesn't make sense.

You'd want to split rather than just replacing periods, but also your data strings aren't period-separated; it's almost space-separated, but you also have data strings that have internal spaces ("Homeowner free and clear"), so you can't just split on spaces.  You'd have to be more clever in splitting up the strings into the columnar data you want.  Or, hopefully, your data is more cleanly set up elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, the Excel data file was the issue. Thanks for your help